# What is the equivalent ManyToMany `through Model` on a ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class ListA(models.Model):
     people = models.ManyToManyField(People, through=ListAMembership)

class ListB(models.Model):
      pass

class People(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()
     listb_membership = models.ForeignKey(ListB)

class ListAMembership(models.Model):
     date_joined = models.DateTimeField()
     list = models.ForeignKey(ListA)
     person = models.ForeignKey(People)

class ListBMembership(models.Model):
     date_joined = models.DateTimeField()
```

Here are the conditions:

**List A**

- `ListA` objects can have many people and `People` objects can be on many ListA objects
- Details of memberships between `People` and `ListA` are recorded on `ListAMembership`

**List B**

- `ListB` objects can have many people but each `Person` can only be on one `ListB` objects

What is the best way to record additional details concerning the membership of ListB in the way ListA uses a `through` to access `date_joined` in `ListAMembership`?

I know I can just add fields to `People` concerning the `ListBMembership`, but is there a cleaner way to keep details of this relationship separate?

Comment: There is no "through" model for a `ForeignKey`. The `through` model is just a model with two `ForeignKey`s to the two items you link to (and optionally extra fields).

Comment: Since here a `Person` is on one list, you record the information on the `Person` itself.

Comment: "Each Person can only be on one List" then the foreign key should be from `People` to `List`

Comment: Should `date_joined` be on the `People` model? You don't need the `Membership` at all I think?

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem  I think I have phrased the question poorly. Please see my edit for a better problem set.

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, I have updated the problem set to better express the question